# С помощью какой библиотеки можно классифицировать данные представленные в двумерном массиве с бинарными значениями?

Tags: c#, python-3.x, машинное-обучение, tensorflow, поиск-библиотек

С помощью какой библиотеки можно классифицировать данные представленные в  двумерном массиве с бинарными значениями?

У меня есть данные которые я могу перевести в виде чернобелых картинок, а дальше использовать стандартные механизмы для классификации картинок по категориям. Но мне хотелось бы избежать шага - перевода данных в картинки, а также использовать тот факт, что данные это битовая матрица использовать для оптимизации по скорости обучения и распознования. Плюс картинок - может быть очень большое кол-во и подгружать всех их из имидж файлов было бы не оптимально.

Comment: Библиотек то полно, хоть самая типовая `scikit-learn`, но что-то я не уверен, что для игр с некими правилами такой подход будет работать. Нейросетями вроде того же `tensorflow/keras` может и удастся какие-то "шаблоны" выделить. В общем, надо смотреть данные, я не уверен, что это "взлетит".

Comment: В общем, можете брать любой классификатор, хоть `Logistic regression` и пробовать. Миллион сэмплов - это немного для линейных моделей. Вот для бустингов или там нейросетей - это уже может быть существенно.

Comment: Записей реально будет намного больше 10 000 000. В постановке скромно указал миллион.  У меня будет история результатов игр и а также все возможные комбинации с точки зрения выигрыша для каждой игры.   Из всех возможных вариантов для новой игры, я хочу оценить какие потенциально вероятные могут выпасть и для них потребуется оценить потенциальный выигрыш.

Comment: Ну, и 10 млн. не вопрос, но мне кажется полезнее будет, если вы почитаете что-то именно в плане наработок по той игре, для которой всё это делается. Потому что если речь про шашки-шахматы, то там ситуация может сильно меняться чуть не с каждым ходом и там оценка конкретной позиции - это далеко не единственный фактор, там чуть ли не важнее посмотреть возможные дальнейшие ходы и оценить их влияние на ситуацию. Если у вас речь не про эти игры, а про другие, то, опять же, лучше разбираться в специфике этих игр. "Машинное обучение" - это не панацея.

Comment: Я надеюсь с помощью ML выявить скрытые закономерности (по статистике таковые есть).

Comment: @CrazyElf можете помочь и скинуть ссылку на библиотеку с Logistic Regression которая работает с наборами двухмерных массивов?

Comment: А, я понял. Вам нужно воспринимать данные как картинку, а не как таблицу? Ну то есть важно взаимодействие между соседними клетками, например, а не просто значение конкретных клеток? Потому что в простейшем случае вы можете воспринимать 2-мерный набор данных 50x50 как одномерный из 2500 элементов и с таким набором (хоть он и великоват) будет работать любой обычный классификатор, например https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html

Comment: А вот если вам важно взаимодействие соседних клеток и т.п., какие-то шаблоны не на уровне всего поля, а мелких его частей, то нужно использовать нейросети и слои типа Conv2D, такие есть в Tensorflow/Keras

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124450/discussion-between-yuriy-tigiev-and-crazyelf).